# NumberFormatException.forInputString

Tags: java, numberformatexception

Can someone explain why do I get `NumberFormatException.forInputString` for this:

```
string: "01000000000000000000000000000001"
Integer.parseInt(string, 10)
```

and how can I fix it, when I need the positive int representation of the number?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The "01000000000000000000000000000001" is not a valid `int`.

`int` has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive).

---

You can convert it to [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String%29):

```
BigInteger myInt = new BigInteger(myString);
```

Comment: if I need the positive int representation of the number? what can I do?

Comment: You cannot: this integer cannot be represent by an ``int``. You need an other data structure such as BigInteger or a customized one.

Answer (score 2):

`Integer.parseInt` parses a number into an `int`, which is a 32-bit signed integer. The number `1000000000000000000000000000001` is far too large to fit in an `int`.

The largest number you can store in an `int` is 2,147,483,647 (2<sup>31</sup> - 1).

Answer (score 1):

This number is way bigger than [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE).

Answer (score 1):

That's going to exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. From [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE):

> A constant holding the maximum value an int can have, 2<sup>31</sup>-1.

which is **2147483647**

[BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) may be of use to you here, since it'll store an integer of arbitrary precision i.e. practically unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

Input number(01000000000000000000000000000001) is greater than `Interger.MAX_VALUE`, is not parse-able string.

Any value more than 2147483647 and less than -2147483648 is not valid integer.

Find more on [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)